# extracting a specific textstring from html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, alexa-skills-kit

Currently I'm working on an alexa skill (node.js) which reads out todays meals in the canteen. 
I thought of going to the canteen website (http://www.stw-thueringen.de/english/dining-halls/facilities/ilmenau/mensa-ehrenberg.html) and search the html for the breaded coalfish as example.

I only had Java(not Javascript) in uni, so I'm not to great at it, especially combining with html.
I have most of the code ready except the extraction...
so, how do I get a specific string of text out of an html using javascript?

thanks is advance :)

Comment: Just to double check, do you actually mean Java or are you referring to Javascript? If you mean Java, then I would recommend an HTML parser like JSoup.

Comment: i am using javascript. sorry

Comment: @Seitekful Please consider editing your question to clarify that you are using javascript, not java. Also, please retag this question with `javascript`, not `java`.

Comment: all done, thank you!

Comment: Consider researching **Regex** (Regular Expressions), which can act as pattern selectors, allowing you to extract very specific information based on contextual patterns.

Comment: Upvoting @Santi's suggestion because this is something I have done many times in the past, but I will say, doing text extraction/scraping this way is a bit of a pain because if the HTML for the page changes, it can easily break your RegEx patterns. Speaking from experience on this matter, I would recommend writing your regex as loose as reasonably possible so it still only matches the specific elements you want to extract, but it will not break if, for example, a new attribute is added to the element(s). You might consider Googling "web scraping with node.js" to look for better options.

Comment: I actually just did the Google search I suggested above and the following looks promising: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio Cheerio supposedly wraps jQuery to provide a server-focused version that can be used within Node.JS. I'm not sure if you have ever used jQuery, but it provides some excellent tools for DOM manipulation, matching, etc. That definitely looks like it might be a viable solution to your problem.